# Android : Make hidden TextView within a ListView item take whole place available when unhiding it

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm pretty new to android development. So I have a simple activity that holds a `LinearLayout`. This `LinearLayout` holds several buttons. Below each button, there is a `ListView` that is hidden. The button serves as hiding/unhiding the corresponding `ListView`. Each item of those `ListView` consist of a button and a hidden `TextView`. Those subbuttons serve as hiding/unhiding the corresponding `TextView`. Until this point, everything goes right except for two things. 
a) When unhiding a `TextView`, I wish that the unhidden `TextView` takes the whole place, in my case it is limited by the height of the `ListView`.
b) When hiding/unhiding `TextView` with one of the subbuttons, the order of the reste of the buttons is changed.

A few images and codes to understand it better:

The Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_theory);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    //ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapterTitleArray);

    for(int i = 0; i<titles.length; ++i){
        Button chapterButton = new Button(this);
        initChapter(chapterButton, titles[i], ll);
    }
}

private void initChapter(Button b, String chapterTitle, LinearLayout ll){
    rowItems.clear(); //For next chapter button
    //Adding Button
    b.setText(chapterTitle);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(b,lp);

    //Adding listview
    final CustomListView subChaptersList = new CustomListView(this);
    lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ll.addView(subChaptersList, lp);

    subChapterTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.subChapterTitleArray);
    descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chapterTextArray);
    for(int i = 0; i<subChapterTitles.length; i++){
        RowItem item = new RowItem(subChapterTitles[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }
    CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
    subChaptersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    subChaptersList.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    subChaptersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    //Listener for Button
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            subChaptersList.setVisibility((subChaptersList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

The adapter:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
Context c;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public CustomBaseAdapter(Context c, List<RowItem> items){
    this.c = c;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    final Button b;
    final TextView t;

    public ViewHolder(final View convertView, int pos){
        b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        t = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(pos);
        b.setText(rowItem.getButtonText());
        t.setText(rowItem.getText());
        t.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                t.setVisibility((t.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                        ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}

public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView, pos);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos){
    return rowItems.get(pos);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos){
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(pos));
}
```

The custom `ListView` I use for changing the height of the `ListView` depending of the content:

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {
public CustomListView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListView  (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomListView  (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int expandSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2,
            View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
}
```

So here's the activity when First button is pressed (everything fine here thanks to the custom `ListView`):

[image: activity when First button is pressed]

And here's the activity when first subbutton is pressed:

[image: First subbutton pressed]

Notice how the `TextView` isn't taking the entire available place for displaying the entirety of the text. Also the other two subbuttons are switched ("Point3" switched with "Point2"). Hiding/unhiding again does the switch again.

I tried several solution, my first approach was to use a `LinearLayout` holding a `ListView` with each item holding a `Button`/`ListView` with each item holding a button/text. I read that embedded `ListView` were bad practice so I came up with that solution that almost does the trick except my problem. I believe that changing the height of the `ListView` dynamically by taking into account the height of the `TextView` could be a solution but I don't really know where to dos this modification.

Comment: Maybe you can change your approach a little and try using an ExpandableListView. It will give you the functionality you want almost out of the box.

Comment: Thank you @ale.m , ExpandableListView solved my problem ;)

Comment: You are welcome :)